# Validate phone field with javascript without using onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem that's probably simple but i cannot change the moment of the validation.

There is a phone field with a mask that accepts 8 digits:

```
$(idDDDTelefone).mask('99999999', {
    placeholder : " "
});
```

But a recent change on phone system added a 9 digit on some numbers.
I cannot just change the mask to 9 digits cause it wont accept 8 digits phone numbers.
How can I do this?
Theres any minlenght function?

Comment: what about international phone numbers with `+XX` or `00XX` at the beginning?

Comment: Are you using [this](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)?

Comment: I have separated fields for those digits. Each one has its own validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the optional character after the 8th digit.

```
$('.phone').mask('99999999Z', {translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true}}});
```

Comment: But it's only one field

Comment: Oh got it - then you need to use optional character

Comment: Updated answer for optional